# Laravel : how to create unique tag in tags model

Tags: laravel, tags

I want create tag for posts . I don't want tags repetitions to be saved,But it is stored repeated

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $post = Post::create($data);
    if ($post && $post instanceof Post) {
        $tags = $request->input('tags');
        foreach ($tags as $tag){
                $newTag = Tag::create(['name'=>$tag]);
                $tags[] = $newTag->id;
        }
            $post->tags()->sync($tags);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateOrCreate` method will help [check](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent)
It will create data if it not exists and update in case it already in db

```
Tag::updateOrCreate(['name'=>$tag]);
```